# php mysql db connect very slow

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small PHP framework that basically just loads a controller and a view.
An empty page loads in about 0.004 seconds, using microtime() at the beginning and end of execution.

Here's the "problem". If I do the following:

$link = @mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass,$link);
@mysql_select_db($database, $link);

the page loads in about 0.500 seconds. A whopping 12500% jump in time to render the empty page.

is this normal or am I doing something seriously wrong here... (I'm hoping for the latter).

**EDIT:** Could someone say what a normal time penalty is for just connecting to a mysql db like above.

Comment: I wouldn't use the error supressor if I were you, especially when you're looking for errors ;) and then, why the $link in your connect?

Comment: the link is only there to open other connects. but in this case it gets passed as false.
removing the @-sign does nothing.

Comment: Do you know how long it takes for a database connection to be established in general? And how long it takes to select a db? I mean before you were just loading a blank page, now you're loading a page, creating a ressource and using it with a query.

Comment: Make sure you're doing lazy connections. Meaning that you would establish the connection only shortly before executing a query.

Comment: @tharkun I'm not executing a query. Only connecting. That's the issue here.

Comment: mysql_select_db is also kind of a query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Error suppression with @](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) will slow down your script. Also an SQL connection is reliant on the speed of the server. So if the server is slow to respond, you will get a slow execution of your script.

Comment: I guess that has got to be it.
The server is probably just that slow to connect to then. 
I just wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something seriously funny here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't get what you're trying to do with the `$link` variable .
`$link = @mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass,$link);` is probably wrong, possibly not doing what you want (ie nothing in your example) unless if you have more than one link to databases (advanced stuff)

[the php.net documention states](http://en.php.net/mysql_connect)

> new_link
>
> If a second call is made to
>   `mysql_connect()`  with the same
>   arguments, no new link will be
>   established, but instead, the link
>   identifier of the already opened link
>   will be returned. The *new_link*
>   parameter modifies this behavior and
>   makes `mysql_connect()` always open a
>   new link, even if `mysql_connect()`
>   was called before with the same
>   parameters. In SQL safe mode, this
>   parameter is ignored.

On my webserver, the load time is always about the same on average (4000 µsecs the first time and 600 µsec the second time)

Half a second to connect to a mysql database is a bit slow but not unusual either. If it's on another server on the network with an existing load, it might be absolutely normal.

I wouldn't  worry too much about this problem.

(oh, old question ! Nevermind, still replying)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried verifying your data integrity?  do a repair table, and an optimze table to all tables.  I know that sometimes when a table has gone corrupt the connection time can take an enormous amount of time / fail all together.

Answer (score 0):

May be the reason is domain resolve slow.

> skip-name-resolve

Add this to my.cnf, then restart mysqld.

And if you skip-name-resolve, you can't use hostname in mysql for user permission.